# OSX takes several attempts to connect to internet over WiFi

Tags: macos, network, wifi

When I start my mac my WiFi connects to my router as normal, however it never has an internet connection. I'm connected to my rounter and can log in to it I just don't have an active internet connection. If I turn off WiFi and reconnect it will eventually work, but it may take 4/5 restarts for this to work.

It's like this for all WiFi networks so it's not an isolated problem..

I've tried obvious stuff (restart router, delete connection) as well as the guide in this link http://osxdaily.com/2012/11/30/resolving-stubborn-wi-fi-connection-problems-in-mac-os-x/ with no success...

Would anyone know how to fix this.

I'm running 10.8.4

Comment: Please clarify, is it only with your router or any non router wifi